# ArrayList java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

i edit the my code to slove the last prob but now when  i'm doing  System.out.println(uns.get(0));  i get NULL  but  System.out.println(uns.get(0)); it i ger result !!!! oopps

```
   Ok I SOLVE THE PROB NOW  i'm adding  uns=new ArrayList(10);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
    uns.add(null);
    }     to Construct

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rNTa.png
```

and i edit these instruction

```
if(i==0)
{ uns.add(i,u);

}
if(i==1)
{
uns.add(i,u);

}   
i++;
```

Thank for all

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)   {                                     
int ligneNom =   jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int colonneNom = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();

     row = new Vector();
    if(colonneNom==0)
    {   
        try {

            int numUnite=Integer.parseInt(jTable1 .getValueAt(ligneNom, 0).toString());
             operation3 o3=new operation3();
             uns=new ArrayList(10);
             for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
              uns.add(null);
             }

             System.out.println(numUnite);
             u=o3.getUnite(numUnite);
             System.out.print(u);
             uns.add(i,u);
             System.out.println(uns.get(0));
             System.out.println(uns.get(1));


            i++;

            row.add( jTable1 .getValueAt(ligneNom, 0));
            row.add( jTable1 .getValueAt(ligneNom, 1));
            model.addRow(row);
            jTable1.clearSelection();

       } catch (NamingException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(employeihm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Where is `i` coming from?

Comment: Basically we don't have nearly enough information here. Ideally, you should come up with a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, but you should *at least* get rid of anything extraneous, and include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is here:

```
            uns=new ArrayList(10);
```

This creates a list whose *capacity* is 10 ... but that initially contains zero elements.

Then you call this:

```
            uns.add(i,u)
```

and we can infer from the exception message that `i` is `1`.  Of course, `1` is outside of the current indexable range of the list, and so you get that exception.

If your intent is that `uns` should be initialized with 10 elements, then you need to "fill" the array after creating it; e.g.

```
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
                uns.add(someValue);
            }
```

(There are 3rd party library methods that will create a list filled with with a given value.  But for something this simple I wouldn't go hunting ...)

Comment: but it is this solution i must fix the size of ListArray  but in other place i want to put a dinamique ArrayList without  size How i can do this ?

Comment: i redirect  the problem  to other  solution Thank you   again =)

Comment: uns.add(0,u);  System.out.println(uns.get(0)it is stay NULL !!

Comment: @Userstackoverflow - Yes.  It will.  It is time for you to **read the javadoc**!! That will explain what the `add` method actually does.

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` is not sparse. You cannot add items for random positions that haven't been set yet. You can only insert items between position 0 and `size()`. This is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) behavior:

> **Throws:**
>       `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index > size())`

Your code tries to add an item to position 1, while position 0 hasn't been set yet (the `size()` is 0). You need to just use `add(item)`, or maybe you need to check your assumptions regarding the values of `i`.

Initializing an `ArrayList` using `new ArrayList(10)` does not define the size, only the initial capacity!

Comment: How i can fix the size so ?

Comment: You can only do that by adding items (for example `null`) up to the desired size. See the [answer by Stephen C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22939312/466862).

Comment: thank you it's  work but it is not the nice solution but is okay ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
uns.add(u);
```

Instead of

```
uns.add(i,u);
```

You are receiving the error because you are trying to replace the element in the list at position `i` when there are no elements at that position yet.

Comment: You can use `uns.add(i,u)` with `0 <= i <= uns.size()`. In OP case, `i` worth 1 while `uns` is empty.

Comment: @ssssteffff which is exactly what I stated in my answer.

Comment: `add(position, item)` ndoes not replace the original item on position, it inserts the new item, moving the original items on position and beyond by one.

Comment: yes i'm using uns.add(u)  i want to add defferent Unite to ArrayList when i'm using add(u) i can insert one entity  so  i get  this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1   when i can to  show data on  ArrayList How  i can  solve this prob so !!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yet it cannot "insert" it if there are no elements at that spot, which technically means that it replaces the item at that index and nudges everything else forward. But this is not the place to argue semantics.

Comment: @user2797404 using `uns.add(u)` multiple times will continue adding elements in sequence, so if you want to add multiple entities one after then just calling `uns.add(u)` will add them one after the other and you don't have to worry about their sequence. Calling it once will place `u` at `uns.get(0)` calling it again will place `u` at `uns.get(1)` etc.

Comment: @CeilingGecko You can only insert between existing items (and directly before the first or after the last)

Answer (score 0):

You create an empty ArrayList with new ArrayList(10). This array list has an initial capacity of 10 elements, but it is still empty as long as you don't add anything into it.

When you access the ArrayList with i > 0, then you will get the exception.

Try to use instead:

```
uns.add(u)
```